# How to separate IpcMain.on from Main.ts?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, electron

At My Index.ts (Main.ts)

```
const createWindow = (): void => {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    height: 768,
    width: 1024,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: false,
      contextIsolation: true,
      preload: MAIN_WINDOW_PRELOAD_WEBPACK_ENTRY,
    },
    autoHideMenuBar: true,
    frame: false
  });

  mainWindow.loadURL(MAIN_WINDOW_WEBPACK_ENTRY);
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
};

ipcMain.on('store_info_update', (event, storeInfo) => {
  console.log('store_info_update')
  const delete_qry = 'DELETE from store '
  const qry = `INSERT INTO store(${storeInfo.key}) VALUES ?`

  // This is my node mysql table update function
  updateTable(delete_qry, qry, storeInfo.values, event, 'store updated')
})
```

I want to separate my ipcMain function to another file called ipcMain_database.ts(React part) to manage function effectively (I have another 6 function to connect to database)

[image]

How can I do? When I just made ipcMain_database.ts file and write ipcMain.on() made error.... Someone said I can make global.share variable, but isn't it nodeIntegration: true is dangerous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just cut your `ipcMain.on()` function from your `main.ts` file and paste it into your `ipcMain_database.ts` file.

`main.ts` (main process)

```js
const createWindow = (): void => {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    height: 768,
    width: 1024,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: false,
      contextIsolation: true,
      preload: MAIN_WINDOW_PRELOAD_WEBPACK_ENTRY,
    },
    autoHideMenuBar: true,
    frame: false
  });

  mainWindow.loadURL(MAIN_WINDOW_WEBPACK_ENTRY);
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
};
```

---

**IMPORTANT:** Don't forget to require the `ipcMain` module in your `ipcMain_database.ts` file.

`ipcMain_database.ts` (main process)

```js
const ipcMain = require('electron').ipcMain; // <-- Don't forget this

ipcMain.on('store_info_update', (event, storeInfo) => {
  console.log('store_info_update')
  const delete_qry = 'DELETE from store '
  const qry = `INSERT INTO store(${storeInfo.key}) VALUES ?`

  // This is my node mysql table update function
  updateTable(delete_qry, qry, storeInfo.values, event, 'store updated')
})
```

Comment: It said 'Error occurred in handler for 'store_info_update': No handler registered for 'store_info_update''